# How would I read Memory into a wstring?

Tags: c++, wstring

I already tried using wchar_t and a for-loop to read the Memory wchar by wchar and it worked.
Working code:

```
int cl = 20;
std::wstring wstr;
wchar_t L;
for (int i = 0; i < cl; i++) {
ReadProcessMemory(ProcHandle, (unsigned char*)Address, &L, 2, NULL);
Address += 2;
wstr.push_back(L);
}
std::wcout << wstr << std::endl;
```

Now when I try using std::wstring and read directly into it, it fails for whatever reason.

```
int cl = 20;
std::wstring L;
L.resize(cl); // could use reserve?
ReadProcessMemory(ProcHandle, (unsigned char*)Address, &L, cl*2, NULL);
std::wcout << L << std::endl;
```

I figured I'd use `(cl * 2)` as size because wchar_t has 2 chars size.

I would expect it to print the wstring to wcout but instead it errors with something similar to `Failed to read sequence`

Note: I cannot use wchat_t[20] because I later want cl to be dynamic.

Edit: Forgot to say that I'm on std c++17

Comment: "because wchar_t has 2 chars size." - Are you *really* sure you are actually *guaranteed* that?

Comment: Please include the exact error message in the question, not just "something similar"

Comment: `// could use reserve?` No. Reserve doesn't actually grow the size of your string. You would still be writing beyond the bounds of your string (even if you *know* the allocated memory is good for it). For example, the data may not be properly copied if you make a copy of `L`. As far as it knows, the size would still be 0 so it would try to copy 0 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::vector<wchar_t>` is more suitable for your case.

`&L` is the address of the string object, not the string buffer. You wanna use `&L[0]`, the address of the first wchar.

Comment: even better, `L.data()`

Comment: `.data()` == better.

Comment: Agree. But we don't know which C++ is used by OP.

Comment: By which c++ you mean which standard? Because it should work even without c++11.

Comment: @unlut well, yes and no. mutable `.data()` is C++17 only, which is needed by OP.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Please correct me if I am mistaken, but he is not changing the internal pointer. He is only trying to write into an already allocated buffer? Its like vector<char> vec;
    vec.resize(1000);
    scanf("%s", vec.data());

Comment: @unlut `.data()` (for basic_string) returns a pointer to const before C++17. So writing into it need a pointer to mutable data.

Comment: This works! Thank you! I had to cast it to a LPVOID though (which obviously wasn't a big task)